# Jquery-ui datepicker with ransack

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to set a date range filter with ransack. So in my view:

```
 <%= f.text_field :DATE_gteq, :id => "datepicker" %>
 <%= f.text_field :DATE_lteq, :id => "datepicker" %>
```

And I'm using jquery-ui datepicker.

To set it up:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

application.js

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker

$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

application.scss

```
@import 'jquery-ui/datepicker';
```

application.html.erb

```
 <script>
      $(function() {
          $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
  </script>
  </body>
```

The problem is that in view when I click on the first search field it does show the calendar, when I click on the second one nothing happens.

What could be the cause?

Comment: You can't have multiple id's in same page use class instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: You can't have multiple duplicate id's on same page

Use a class in the view and call as below:

```
$('.datepicker').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Gotta wait 10 minutes but I will!

Comment: Just noticed that after searching the first field shows the choosen date, the second filter doesn't. It's just blank. But both works, results are filtered correctly..

Comment: Are you doing and ajax call or something

Comment: I really wouldn't know how to check that. The setup for ransack and datepicker is all in the question..

Comment: actually I am not aware of ransack I just saw the datepicker issue and answered it. May be ransack is doing something after search

Comment: Alright that's a minor issue anyway I'll look into it better and make another question in case. Thanks again!

Comment: That would be better